# Как сделать так чтобы после удаления элемента массива при повторном его добавлении обратно он был в том же месте что изначально в плане нахождения?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue3

```
const selectedColumn = (item) => {
      originalColumnsList.value = originalColumnsList.value.filter((column) => column.id != item.id);
      selectedColumns.value.push(item);
      saveDisabled.value = false;
    }
```

в функции selectedColumn() идет удаление элемента массива originalColumnsList.value и нужно понять как потом при необходимости добавить новый элемент с такими же данными и чтобы он был в том же месте где и до удаления в плане расположения в массиве

Comment: Когда удаляете элемент, запоминайте его индекс перед удалением. Когда по-новой добавляете, добавляйте по сохраненному индексу. Найти индекс можно при помощи `findIndex` или `indexOf`, а добавить по индексу можно с помощью `splice`.

Comment: Выглядит так, как будто Вы делаете что-то не правильно.  Судя по именам переменных и Вашего небольшого объяснение "вангую", что массив отвечает за какие-то столбцы, которые добавляются и удаляются в GUI. Если это так, то почему бы не добавить в объект столбца (если его нет , то создать) свойство отвечающее за его видимость? В коде, который отвечает за визуальное отображение столбцов использовать добавленное свойство для отображения/скрытия?